# asp.net MVC DisplayNameFor property with datatype object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working with asp.net mvc and using the class property as a type object because I need to use of object type. My class is:

```
public class Session
{
    public object SessionId { get; set; }
    public object SessionYear { get; set; }
}
```

I have pitched the data from the model to the Controller and displayed it in the View, but the problem is when I am using `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>item.SessionYear)` and post the Http Request, the sessionYear converts from the object to a string but the string variable has System.String data instead of the actual data from the form.

My View is:

```
    @model HygeneMed.MVC.Models.Session
    @Html.BeginForm("SaveSession","Session")
    {       
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.SessionYear);  
        <input type="submit" value="Save Session">
    }
```

The real problem is I am using object instead of string so I'm getting this error. Please help.

Comment: If you are posting back data, you need to create inputs (e.g. using @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Session.Year) or @Html.TedxtBoxFor(m => m.Session.Year)

Comment: sorry I am not using IEnumberable or List .

Comment: That has nothing to do with it. In order to post back your model to your controller you need to create an input for each property of your model.